# Change BindingContext/BindingSource Maui

Tags: mvvm, maui

So I reckon I've confused myself a tad and would live some help.
I wish to change the binding source to a property contained within my viewmodel from the viewmodel itself.

This is part of my view

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FoodopolyClientV2.Views.GamePage"
             Title="GamePage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:FoodopolyClientV2.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:GameViewModel"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FoodopolyClientV2"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FoodopolyClientV2.Controls"
             >
...

<controls:BoardSpaceView
            BindingContext="{Binding boardSpaces[1]}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            SpaceName="{Binding name}"
            SetOrType="{Binding setOrType}"
            x:Name="Pos1"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource BoardSpaceViewControlTemplate}"/>
...
```

and my viewmodel:

```
public partial class GameViewModel:ObservableObject
{
...
    public BoardSpaceViewRecord[] boardSpaces;
...
//boardSpaces populated in constructor
...
}
```

I'm trying to change the binding source of the BoardSpaceView to a record in boardSpaces, is this even possible? I want to bind to the name & setOrType properties of my record.

Thanks.

Comment: For  the element in your ControlTemplate, you should also use [TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate#pass-parameters-with-templatebinding) to bind the property of the element to the templated parent.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your VM called `SelectedSpace` that points to whatever element of `boardSpaces` you want to display

```
[ObservableProperty]
BoardSpaceViewRecord selectedSpace;
```

then bind your XAML to it (you don't need to modify the `BindingContext`)

```
SpaceName="{Binding SelectedSpace.name}"
SetOrType="{Binding SelectedSpace.setOrType}"
```

then in your VM you can change the displayed space by updating the property

```
SelectedSpace = boardSpaces[3];
```